# how to design a database model to record client's history activity?

Tags: android, mysql, database, database-design, content-management-system

In my App,a question answering application.I seleced MySql as its database.Once user A answer user B's question Q in time X,I should push a message to B that A had answered Q.Reasonablly,I should also record these two things,one is for A that you answer B's question Q in time X,another one is for B that you question Q is answered by A in time X.Correspondingly,these records should be able to be reviewed by users in the future.
  How I should to design a db system to save these user historys?
I have three tables:

1. one is for question items

It include a field question_item_xmltree_path saving answer_item_id answerig this question by json just like ["120","121","122"],I know it's a very bad way.
one

2. one is for key items

including some fields descripting keys like raiser_name raising_time

Comment: You should post what you already have till now.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way.
Think of the way you described your entities in text - there are users, questions and answers. Those are the main entities of the system and should be the main tables in your database. Since a user can post many questions, while each question may be posted by a single user, you have a 1:m relationship between these tables. Same goes for questions and answers, and for users and answers.

Long story short - start with this basic design:

```
TblUsers (user details)
TblQuestions (question details, and an fk to tblusers, for the user that asked the question)
TblAnswers (answer details, an fk to tblusers for the user that posted the answer, and an fk to tblquestions for the question that it belongs to).
```

From this structure you can get all the information you need for a basic q&a application.